# Goto vs. Local function in Perl

Tags: perl, function, goto

In Perl, is it better to use `goto` or local function, and why with an example?

For example, I am using a code

```
sub data {
    data;
}

data();
```

or

```
goto L:

L: if ( $i == 0 )
   print "Hello!!!!";
```

Comment: The rule of thumb (in many languages including Perl) is not to use the `goto` statement unless you know exactly why it is needed.

Comment: Looking at this together with [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30691110/622310) you don't appear to have got the hang of writing questions for Stack Overflow. I suggest you take a look at [***How to Ask***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Programmers don't die. They just `GOSUB` without `RETURN`.

That said, do **not** use `goto` in Perl.

- If you want a statement to be executed once, just write that statement and don't use any flow control
- If you want your program to execute the stuff several times, put it in a loop
- If you want them to be executed from different places, put them in a sub
- If you want the sub to be available in different programs, put them in a module
- Don't use `goto`

---

There is one place where a `goto` makes sense in Perl. Matt Trout is talking about that in his blog post [*No, not that `goto`, the other `goto`*](http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/goto-considered-useful/).

Comment: Sometimes you must use goto. If the flowchart looks like the three-utility problem <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water,_gas,_and_electricity>, then a goto is required. Or you can hide the goto in a state machine. It's "goto"-less programming, mean don't use the word "goto". But goto's are required for non-trivial code.

Comment: @shawnhcorey while that might be true, it's not the point here. We are dealing with a beginner. There are almost always exceptions to rules, but sometimes it's a good decision to ommit them initially. :)

Comment: @shawnhcorey you can almost always avoid goto, eg. by using basic blocks http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Basic-BLOCKs

Comment: @simbabque It used to bug the heck out of me that my professors tried to dumb things down. I wanted to know not only the exceptions but how to identify them, so I could use the correct technique to deal with them.

Comment: @Сухой27 "...almost always..." Yes but how do you know when? That takes experience but you may have to use a goto when you cannot create a flowchart without the lines crossing over themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Conventional wisdom is that other constructs are better than goto.

If you want to do something repeatedly, use a loop.

If you want to do something conditionally, use a block with if.

If you want to go somewhere and come back, use a function.

If you want to bail out early and "jump straight to the end", this can often be better written using an exception. (Perl handily manages